# Updating the view after changes to the model classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

When I rename a property in a class of my model (CS file), I usually go to the view and update the it (CSHTML file), since VS doesn't propagate that change into view classes.

Is there a simpler way? I'd like to have a *go get them, boy* button that recreates the view. Of course, it needs to be smart enough to only update the relevant changes and not recreate the whole shabang (in which case all my fronend magic would go poof and I'd go insane).

Comment: try refactor-> rename. resharper does it smartly as well

Comment: You need to post a reply, not comment, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use refactor => rename from visual studio. Or you can use a tool like resharper to do the renaming. It's smart enough to change all the references.

Comment: Ah, you need to go CTRL+r+r **before** the change... I prefer the old way - you type in a change and then form the menu propagate the changes to everything else...   :)

Comment: yes that will be another of doing it. But last few years I am addicted to resharper. it's just helps many ways :)